# Minimum variance estimator Maximum likelihood (ML) vs Least Squares

Tags: least-squares, maximum-likelihood

According to the Gauß Markov theorem, the least squares estimator is the best linear unbiased estimator, given some assumptions.

The maximum likelihood estimator however, has asymptotically minimal variance, i.e. in the limit of large N it has the lowest variance amongst all unbiased estimators.

First I thought that this wasnt a contradiction as these two estimators are equal for a linear model with gaussian noise. However, the Gauß Markov theorem holds even if there is no Gaussian noise, i.e. in cases when the MLE is not equal to the LSE.
Can someone help me to solve this contradiction?

Comment: The maximum likelihood estimator need not be unbiased for finite $N$, and if not then it does not have "the lowest variance amongst all unbiased estimators".

Comment: In this lecture in the last paragraph "5 Appendix: Properties of MLE", it says that it is both asymptotically unbias and that it has asymptotically minimal variance: "Asymptotically minimal variance means that as the amount of data grows, the MLE has the minimal variance among all unbiased estimators".
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading10b.pdf

Comment: But if the maximum likelihood estimator is not unbiased before the infinite limit is reached, than that suggests to me that for finite amounts of data some other estimator actually has the minimal variance among all unbiased estimators.  The MLE may have asymptotically minimal variance and its bias may be arbitrarily small given enough data, but that is not the same thing

Comment: Fair. But the LSE should be, in the specific setting where the Markov theorem holds, the linear estimator with lowest variance, independent of sample size. If we now go to infinite N, in a situation in which the Gauß Markov theorem holds, than both the LSE estimator and the ML estimator should have minimum variance amongst all unbiased estimators - however, they are not equal (if we dont assume gaussian noise). To me this seems to be a contradiction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no contradiction...even if you apply it asymptotically as you discuss in the comments under the question. The MLE is a general estimator that depends on the distribution and is **not necessarily linear**. The GM theorem applied to **linear** estimators.

The MLE is asymptotically the best among almost all estimators that are consistent and asymptotically normal (under minor regularity conditions). It achieves the asymptotic Cramer Rao lower bound.

The linear LSE is the best among all  consistent and asymptotically normal **linear estimators**.

Comment: But isnt a linear estimator a special case of "all estimators"? I.e., shouldnt the MLE be able to provide linear estimators as well? And if so, in that case the ML estimators would compete with the LSE and there could be a contradiction, no?

Comment: No. Whether the MLE is linear and unbiased or not depends on your model and the involved distributions. If your model is such that the MLE is linear and unbiased (Gaussian linear model for example), then the MLE *coincides* with the best unbiased linear estimator. There is no contradiction.